# emu8086 graphics mode delay

Tags: performance, assembly, emu8086, vga

i'm trying to draw a box in emu8086, using graphics mode (vga). for some reason there is a delay between pixel to pixel, which make it looks like animation, instead drawing the box at once.

is there away to overcome this ? the delay in the debugger set to 0.

if needed, please see relevant code below:

```
BORDER:

    mov ax, 13h                     ;; vga mode
    int 10h

    mov cx, 640

BORDER_LOOP:

    push cx 
    mov bh, 0h     
    inc borderX
    mov cx, [borderX]

    mov dx, [borderY]
    mov al, [color]
    mov ah, 0ch
    int 10h
    pop cx
    LOOP BORDER_LOOP
```

Comment: Your loop could obviously be more efficient (e.g. use registers, not memory, and a different reg for the counter to avoid push/pop cx), but presumably most of the time is spent inside the handler for `int 10h`.  How much delay?  Like multiple seconds to paint the whole screen or a whole line, or a small fraction of a second for the whole screen?

Answer (score 2):

`INT 10h / AH=0Ch` is just not a fast way of drawing to the screen. Since you're doing mode 13h, you may as well just write to video memory directly. The segment is `A000`, the address is `320 * y + x` (one byte per pixel, row major order, starting at the top left) — and you can draw horizontal lines (or fill the whole screen) with `REP STOS` and copy chunks of data with `REP MOVS`. In many cases you can go hundreds of times faster than calling the BIOS to draw pixels.